# Jquery nth-child loop

Tags: jquery

I got "N" div containers all with same class "test" and inside i got divs.

How can i change background on hover on only one of the container's divs(all of them).I tryed with `('div').parent('test')` but its hovering all of the containers.

**My code i already tried but its not working:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.test').each(function() {
   $('.test').hover(function() {
    $('div').parent('.test').css('background','#000000');
   },function() {
    $('div').parent('.test').css('background','#FFFFFF');
   }); 
}); 
});
```

**The HTML PART:**

```
<div class="test" data-href="index.php?page=customerinfo&nodeid='.$usernode['id'].'">
                        <div class="col-md-3">

                        '.$usernode['name'].'
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-1">
                      ('.str_pad($usernode['id'],4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).')
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                      '.long2ip($usernode['ipaddr']).'
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                      '.$mac.'
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-1">
                      &nbsp;
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-1">
                      LAN1
                      </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                  <img src="img/access.gif" />
                  <img src="img/warningoff.gif" />
                  <img src="img/delete.gif" />
                  <img src="img/edit.gif" />
                  <img src="img/info.gif" />
                </div></div>
```

there is N containers with class="test" so i dont know how to do it properly

Comment: Can you show some sample html

Comment: Well, it just looks like you want to use `$(this)`  or `$(this).children('div')` instead of `$('div').parent('.test')`. But hard to tell without seeing a minimalistic sample replicating your issue and expected behaviour. None working code usually doesn't really help...

Comment: So what about `$(this).children('div')`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever your `mouseenter class test` it changes it's background.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").on("mouseenter",function(){
    $(this).children('div').css('background','red');
  });
  $(".test").on("mouseleave",function(){
    $(this).children('div').css('background,'none');
  });
});
```

Comment: tried it but still not working if dont use col-md classes to change background its not changing background from .test class

Answer (score 1):

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.test').children('div').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
      $(this).css('background', '#000000');
    }, function() {
      $(this).css('background', '#FFFFFF');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to target descendant `div`s. So ue:

```
$(this).children('div').css(...);
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for frnt's answer + your edit Ty